# Using Google Login with Cognito Identity Pool to Authorize Lambda HTTP Requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless

I'm sure someone must have gone through scenario; however, I have not been able to find some documentation/samples covering it.

**What I'm attempting to do**

- Expose several REST endpoints using Lambda (severless), so this is a registered api with the api gateway
- Some of these endpoints require a user authenticated with Google only

**What I have working**

- Lambda Functions
- Cognito Identity Pool entry created upon successful Google login (no user pool)

**What is the problem**

I do not see how to authorize the endpoints based on the user who has logged in with Google, I had thought given that there is some entry for the user now in the Identity Pool something like the following would work for the http paths to be secured:

> authorizer: aws_iam

or

> authorizer:
>   arn: arn:aws:cognito-identity:us-west-2:XXXXX:identitypool/us-west-2:XXXXX

Do I require a user pool even I am using Google for this? If so how would I link the user pool to the identity pool that is provided by Google?

If someone has a working serverless configuration for this type of deployment they could point me to it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can any user with valid Google credentials call your Lambda functions, or do you want to restrict access to a certain subset of your identity pool?

Comment: @Viccari, yes any user that has been authenticated with Google should be able to access the protected endpoints.

The following issue was opened with several similar comments. From the issue it looks like you might need a user pool and not just an identity pool.

https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/508